# Can I accept two answers?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

If I get two answers that jointly answer the question (one directly answers the question and offers a work-around, and the other offers a thinking-out-of-the-square kind of answer), can I vote for both of them?

Perhaps I mean to accept both of them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot accept both, but you can upvote both.

There can only be one accepted answer that awards 15 reputation to the answerer, but you can upvote as many as you like, that awards 10 reputation points.

You can even upvote the accepted answer, awarding a total of 25 reputation points to the user.

Comment: Great - but I'm n00b and I don't get to vote.

Comment: @phil, you will once you earn a little more reputation, it's not hard!

Comment: Surely you can vote on questions you've asked...? or not?

Comment: @mic, you have 9 questions here on meta, why don't you try it?

Comment: @Downvoter B/c I already have enough rep--my votes aren't restricted like a new, repless user

Comment: oh, ok, I didn't understand what you were saying

Comment: I tried it since I _don't_ have enough rep--and no, you can't immediately vote on your own questions.