# Accepting more than one correct answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I vote for two answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/can-i-vote-for-two-answers)

Sometimes many answers are correct at the same time on one question. Can I accept more than one answer?

Comment: All such question are belong on meta.

Answer (score 5):

What I usually do in cases where there are multiple correct answers is that I accept the most relevant and then upvote all the others that are usefull.

But to answer you question, no, one answer per question.

Comment: How about this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Answer (score 5):

I usually go by the time that the answer was posted, and accept the first one that answered my question. That is, of course, if all competing correct answers are of approximately the same quality.

Otherwise, pick the one that you'd want if you were making a text book. The one that you pick will be on top of the stack, so it should be the most comprehensive answer.

Here's an example of two correct answers that basically say the same thing:

> You need to allocate memory for it.

and

> You can't operate on 'foo' until you
>   have allocated some memory. Do this
>   with malloc() as shown below: (sample
>   follows)

I would hope that the second answer was accepted, since it is the most informative, if not the first one posted.

Not selecting the other doesn't make it any less *correct*, but the one (yes, one only) you can accept should be the most *comprehensive*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

By upvoting all good answers you indicate "goodness" already. By putting additional green accept marks onto all the answers that seem correct to you now shifts the burden of picking the right answer from you (one time operation) to the user (over and over again), which will lead to confusion in the end.

So, no: only one accepted answer, IMHO.